# How to remove inputs from GoodieBag Pinview after checking the pin is false?

Tags: android, authentication

I am using GoodieBag Pinview for login through pin in my app. After entering four-digit pin, it validates the pin. But after validation if the pin enter is wrong the cursor stays at the last box of the pin view. I need to remove all the entries from the pinview boxes and the cursor to move to first box if the pin entered is wrong.

I have another scenario where I set the pin. There I have two pinview, one for enter-pin and other for confirm-pin. After entering the values in enter-pin, I need to move the cursor automatically to confirm-pin first box. But it does not happen. I have to manually click on the confirm-pin first box to set the pin.

How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default method for deleting values from pinView. But am overriding the delete key press event of pinview to clear the value in Pinview.

**Try this**

```
otpPinView.onKey(otpPinView.getFocusedChild(), KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
```

Above code will delete the value of currently focused value in pinview. If you want to clear all values loop through until your **Pin Length**.

I tried something like this

```
for (int i = 0;i < otpPinView.getPinLength();i++) {
        otpPinView.onKey(otpPinView.getFocusedChild(), KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
}
```

**For scenario 2:**

Try this

```
pinview1.setPinViewEventListener(new Pinview.PinViewEventListener() {
    @Override
      public void onDataEntered(Pinview pinview, boolean fromUser) {
            pinview2.requestFocus();
        }
});
```

**Edited**

Note: Pinview is the group of edittext. So if you want to cursor visible in first box that is first edittext you need to set `requestFocus` method to pinview child.

You can try below code

```
pinview1.setPinViewEventListener(new Pinview.PinViewEventListener() {
    @Override
      public void onDataEntered(Pinview pinview, boolean fromUser) {
            pinview2.getChildAt(0).requestFocus(); //0 is index of child.
        }
});
```

Comment: The above code worked like a charm. But in the second scenario after the second pinView gains focus, no cursor is seen in the first box.I have already set the cursorVisible to true in the xml layout but it is not working. How do I make the cursor visible programatically?

Answer (score 2):

Simple and easy way to clear pinview

```
if(codeinvalid){
 //call that method to clear pinview
  clearPinViewChild();
 }
```

Method

```
  private void clearPinViewChild() {
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.getChildCount() ; i++) {
        EditText child = (EditText) pin.getChildAt(i);
        child.setText("");

    }
}
```